# Basis of solution spaces ex

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the dimension over $\mathbb{R}$ of the space of solutions of the following systems of equations. Also find a basis for this space of solutions.

$x-y+z=0$

Using the formula $\text{row rank}+\dim \text{space of solutions}=n$, in which n is the number of variables.

I figured out that $\dim \text{space of solutions}=2$

However, for example the vector (1,1,0) can be a solution.

**Questions**:

**1)** How do I find the basis in a quick way?

**2)** If I had not computed $\dim \text{space of solutions}=2$, I would not know that the basis needed two vectors. How would I know (1,1,0) could not be a basis?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you tell what is the set of the solutions of the given equasion?

Comment: By the way, I suppose you are talking about $\mathbb{R}^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that all the vectors in that subspace satisfy the equation: $x-y+z=0 \implies x=y-z$. So if we take a generic vector, $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z  \end{pmatrix}$ it must satisfy that equation. So, we put $x=y-z$ and we obtain that:

$$W=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z  \end{pmatrix} | x=y-z\right\}= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} y-z \\ y \\z  \end{pmatrix} | y,z \in \mathbb{K}\right\}= Span \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\0  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} $$

by putting first $y=1$ and then $z=1$.